# File ownership and access

Tags: windows, solaris, file-permissions

I have an established workflow, but a change has caused some complications. An upstream Windows server delivers a file to my Solaris server where the file is accessed by my Windows 2003 server.

The problem is that either the ownership or permissions on a file delivered daily to the Solaris server has changed, and now the service running on my Windows server cannot copy and delete the file.

My Windows server has a parent directory on the Solaris server mapped and authenticated by User1.

The failing file comes in with an ownership of User2 and permissions of 664.

The failing file can be copied and deleted directly through Windows Explorer without additional authentication. A scheduled task batch file also can perform the copy and delete without authentication. It is only the running service which is unable to perform these tasks.

For comparison, there are a collection of files following the same workflow. These have an of ownership of User1 and permissions of 755.

User1 is a member of User1.

User2 is a member of staff.

The Solaris directory holding the files has permissions of 755 and ownership of User1.

What change can I make to give my Windows services ongoing access to files with both ownerships?

UPDATE:
Using a persistent shell script to change the ownership.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to use a persistent shell script to edit the file ownership.